# Colorbox You tube video

Tags: javascript, files

I am using [Youtube](https://www.drupal.org/project/youtube) module and [colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox).  I have a content type with a youtube thumbnail in the teaser.  If you click on it, I would like it to open in a colorbox with dimensions 420x315.  Instead it opens in the full browser window.

I have youtube colorbox module installed and enabled, but when I got to  configure the thumbnail, it mentions colorbox but not youtube-colorbox.  Don't know if this could be the problem.

I've tried linking the thumbnail to both colorbox and youtube but I get the same result in either case.  I am Drupal default Field template for the thumbnail.

Any ideas how I can get this to open in a colorbox?